# looping for dynamic data

Tags: java, android, class, loops

I have this code:

```
entryData = new Entry[] { 
        new Entry( path1, name1, tag1 ),
        new Entry( path2, name2, tag2 ),
        new Entry( path3, name3, tag3 ),
        new Entry( path4, name4, tag4 )
};
```

The data above gives my list view 4 items (rows). That works fine.

But if I loop, for example:

```
for(x=0; x<4; x++){
    entryData = new Entry[] { new Entry( pathx, namex, tagx ) };
}
```

My list view shows one item (row) only...

My class code is:

```
public class Entry {
    public String icon;
    public String title;
    public String tag;

    public Entry() {
        super();
    }

    public Entry(String icon, String title, String tag) {
        super();
        this.icon = icon;
        this.title = title;
        this.tag = tag;
    }
}
```

Any ideas? I'm just learning it again! TIA!!!

Comment: you have to initialize the array before use and also suggested to use arraylist so as to add dynamic elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array must be defined before the loop. Each iteration should only add an element to the array:

```
entryData = new Entry[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    entryData[i] = new Entry(pathx, namex, tagx);
}
```

If you don't know the size of the array in advance, then use a List instead, which grows dynamically:

```
List<Entry> entryData = new ArrayList<Entry>();
// ...
for (int i = 0; i < someDynamicValue; i++) {
    entryData.add(new Entry(pathx, namex, tagx));
}
```

Also, please respect the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 2):

You missed out [x], and you should initialize the array before the loop. It should looks like this:

```
entry_data = new Entry[4];
for(x=0; x<4; x++){
    entry_data[x] = new Entry( pathx, namex, tagx );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `List` instead of `Array` for dynamic case. `ArrayList` is resizable-array implementation of it. You

```
List<Entry> entry_data  = new ArrayList<Entry>();
for(x=0; x<4; x++){
    entry_data.add(new Entry( pathx, namex, tagx ));
}
```

and in [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) -

> Each ArrayList instance has a capacity. The capacity is the size of the array 
>   used to store the elements in the list. It is always at least as large as the 
>   list size. As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically.
>   The details of the growth policy are not specified beyond the fact that adding 
>   an element has constant amortized time cost.